# API for external access

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I need to develop an API using ASP.NET CORE 3.1 for an external company to update some subscription data.

This API is going to be used for a mobile app, and we are using a JWT bearer token to identify the users, so when a user logs in to the mobile app, we create a token and after that, all the methods of the API check the JWT to verify the user logged in. Until this, no problem and everything works just fine.

But we have an agreement with a external company to make some payments in their app, so we need to provide them an API method so everytime someone pays we can update our database. The problem is we have no control over this company app.

My question is, how can we protect that API method so we are sure only the calls from this external company app can get and update our database, but no one else can do it? A simple password?

Comment: You could use an VPN tunnel (IPSec/StrongSwan) or similar. Then the API is only listening for traffic going through the VPNTunnel.

Comment: Could you please give me more info about this option?

Answer (score 0):

Using VPN Tunnel it is running securely between to parties as if it was running lan.

> strongSwan is a complete IPsec solution providing encryption and authentication to servers and clients.
>   It can be used to secure communications with remote networks, so that connecting remotely is the same as
>   connecting locally.

*StrongSwan is one of the solutions, many other products can do the same.*

https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IntroductionTostrongSwan